# How to Insert foreignKey Value in SQLite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table tableGrupo (Groups) that has a foreign key from other table tableMaquinas (Machines).  When I am inserting data in the table tableGrupo (Groups), Android Studio tells me that the foreign key field must not be null because it is a foreign key.

What value should I attribute in order to have the insertion accepted and pass it the proper foreign key id?

This is my code:

```
 //Table1
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ tableGrupo +" ("+
                idGrupo +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                nomeGrupo +" TEXT)");

        //Table2
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ tableMaquinas +" ("+
                idMaquina +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + nomeMaquina + " text not null, "
                + imagemMaquina + " BLOB, "
                + id_grupo + " integer, "
                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+id_grupo+") REFERENCES "+tableGrupo+"("+idGrupo+"))");


**This is the code where I make the insertion in the database**

 public void addMachine(String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
        ContentValues values = new  ContentValues();
        values.put(nomeMaquina,name);
        values.put(imagemMaquina,image);
        //here i have to put a value for the foreignkey
        this.getWritableDatabase().insert(tableMaquinas,null,values);
    }
```

Comment: the idea of databases with relationship is, that it can access that data where th FOREIGN KEY points to. So the id where the FOREIGN KEY points to should already exist. If it doesn´t it makes no sense for such kind of database. And if it exists, your key is not null. So maybe there is a little misunderstanding...you must have a valid FOREIGN KEY...

Comment: But android studio keeps bugging me that the value of the foreign key is null when I add something and it must not be!

Comment: you never attribute a value to id_grupo, therefore, sqlite cant associate your Maquina to a Grupo  (by the way, highly recommended to standardize variable naming - id_grupo OR idGrupo in all tables).  Android Studio is not an agent, it is simply an IDE (ambiente interativo de desenvolvimento) code runs on a physical or virtual device (the emulator is not android studio proper - o emulador de dispositvos virtuais, caso esteja usando, não é o android studio, / é o equivalente a um plugin) - that is where the error occurs, even though you might be seeing it using the AVD / Android Monitor window.

Comment: another mistake: it is not tableGrupo that has a foreign key FROM another table, it is tableMaquinas which gets its value from tableGrupo.

Comment: This is whats happening!

Comment: see what `SQLiteDatabase#insert` method returns

Comment: Show the actual error message.

Answer (score 2):

Your table `tableMaquinas` defines a column `id_group` as an integer which has a foreign key pointing to a primary key column in the `tableGrupo` table.  So, beyond the requirement is that it has to point to a record in the `tableGrupo` table which actually exists.

Here is code which should work with your current schema:

```
ContentValues values = new  ContentValues();
values.put(idGrupo, 1);
this.getWritableDatabase().insert(tableGrupo, null, values);

ContentValues values = new  ContentValues();
values.put(nomeMaquina, name);
values.put(imagemMaquina, image);
values.put(id_grupo, 1);
this.getWritableDatabase().insert(tableMaquinas, null, values);
```

Note that I have assumed that certain variables above exist (most already do), but you might have to slightly alter the above code to get it to work in your particular method.

Comment: But in this way the foreign key it will always be "1" and will always point to the first row of the tableGrupo  no matter how many insertation I made? or am I wrong?!

Comment: It is up to you to decide how you want to resolve this problem.  I only gave you a working example so you can see how you need to handle things.  Of course, you can replace `1` with a variable corresponding to the particular group.

Comment: How can I query a group and obtain an id of them without the use of Cursor?

Comment: You _shouldn't_ be querying for a group when inserting into the machine table, you should already _have_ a group in hand.  If not, then maybe the real problem is your database design, or how you plan on using it.

Comment: But I need a way to know in witch  group I am, for example I am in the page where the name of the group is "Nice people" I have to query in order to have the id of that group and then pick up that id and put it in the insertion for put information only inside that group like "people inside it"(that only belong to that group) right?

Comment: José, cuidado, vc está perigosamente perto de infringir as regras do que pode ou nao ser perguntado.  Voce nao pode pedir para fazerem seu codigo para vc.  Recomendo que vc estude mais sobre desenho de bases de dados, pois suas perguntas indicam que vc desconheceria o basico.

Translation in a nutshell: you are dangerously close to asking for others to code for you.  Recommend that you learn/study about db design and usage, because your questions indicate that you dont quite grasp the basics yet.

Comment: ps: you should AT LEAST upvote Tim's answer, though i recommend that you accept it, because it is correct and he went out of his way to correct a very basic coding error of yours.  You should not expect him to write your code for you.  Welcome to StackOverflow, meu irmão.  :)

Comment: @tonygil Que sabe que la lengua usanda aquí es Portugués e no Español?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why are you mentioning "not null"? Only the name column has such a constraint.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you caught me red-handed, LMHO.  Actually, i dont know if it is spanish or portuguese, but i assumed portuguese because im brazilian and because they are so similar that i expect anyone who speaks one language to understand the other.  Very umbilical of my part.  BUT i did translate it into english and wrote google translate friendly text (no slang)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but i think i have a reasonable workaround. It is possible to save to return value from the insert method and save it in a variable.  If the insert is successful, it will return the `_id` when successful, and `-1` when fail. Here is a reference of the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)).

```
ContentValues values = new  ContentValues();
values.put(idGrupo, 1);
long sucess = this.getWritableDatabase().insert(tableGrupo, null, values);
values.clear();

values.put(nomeMaquina, name);
values.put(imagemMaquina, image);
values.put(id_grupo, success);
this.getWritableDatabase().insert(tableMaquinas, null, values);
```